# Android Studio: when ever I try to run it the app installs but as soon as it launches it crashes

Tags: java, android-studio

My app crashes as soon as it launches. I have checked the Logcat it shows this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference at com.example.creativeeyes.IntroductoryActivity.onCreate(IntroductoryActivity.java:36)
```

This is my java file:

```
public class IntroductoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo, appName, splashImg;
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    private static final int NUM_PAGES =3;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introductory);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        appName = findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        splashImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie_layer_name);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter (pagerAdapter);

        splashImg.animate().translationY(-1600).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        logo.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        appName.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);


    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                OnBoardingFragment1 tab1 = new OnBoardingFragment1();
                return tab1;

                case 1:
                    OnBoardingFragment2 tab2 = new OnBoardingFragment2();
                    return tab2;

                case 2:
                    OnBoardingFragment3 tab3 = new OnBoardingFragment3();
                    return tab3;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

}
```

The code is correct I dont know why it crashes with that error.
Please guide me.

Comment: Can you check if R.id.pager is the right id for the viewPager? Attach the xml file if possible. Log the viewPager after the findViewById line to check if null is returned

Comment: I assume that this is caused by the call `viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);` returning `null`, so two lines later you get that error when you try to call `viewPager. setAdapter()`.